# who uploaded the artifact to Nexus?

Tags: maven, nexus

1) By looking at the artifact in Nexus, how do I know who uploaded the artifact to Nexus? There are many developers who deploy to Nexus. During maven release process in Jenkins, they provide their AD user name and password.

2) My settings.xml has server id, username and password as well.

I want to know whether developer's username and password was used to deploy or the settings.xml always overrides the developer's user name and password for deployment.

I want to confirm this by looking at some metadata in Nexus as to who deployed it. If I find out that the developer's username and password was used for deployment, I want to see how I can force them all to use a single username and password to deploy.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have Sonatype you can simple see it in the UI

[image]

If you have Nexus Pro you can also get custom metadata:
https://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/reference/custom-metadata-plugin.html

Comment: I noticed that my Nexus also has a "Uploaded by". Your answer helped me pay attention to this. Thank you.